# Does a normal reaction do work too?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

On backflipping off a wall, the wall applies an equal and opposite force that pushes the person in the opposite direction of the applied force. Or, on simply pushing a wall, the wall pushes back. Does it mean that the normal force applied by the wall is doing work on the person pushing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What work is done by the wall when a ball hits it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/463896/)

Comment: The amount of work done (or not done) by a force is an observer dependent quantity (because two observers in relative motion will see the force applied through different displacements...). But that's OK, because the kinetic energy of the object the force is (or is not) working on is *also* an observer dependent quantity. The magic here is that the two dependencies are coupled such that the work-energy theorem is satisfied for all observers.

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless the wall moves. If the force is not applied through a distance, no work is done.